# scatterplotMatrix in R: explanation of options

Tags: r

Quick question about the scatterplotMatrix from the "car" package. I am pulling some data from excel into R to do some analysis, but I'm unsure about some of the lines being plotted and the "car" package info on CRAN isn't too specific. I have the code below:

```
clipboard <- read.table("clipboard",sep="\t",header=T)

view(clipboard)

X1  X2  X3  X4
3   1   5   3
1   1   5   4
2   1   6   1
3   2   5   2
1   1   5   4
2   1   6   5
3   2   6   4
2   2   5   3
3   2   6   2
1   1   5   5
3   2   3   3
2   2   5   4
3   2   3   3
2   2   5   3
3   1   6   5

scatterplotMatrix(~X1+X2+X3+X4,clipboard)
```

Thick red line is regression curve, but what are the dotted lines? Some defined confidence interval bound? I know the diagonals are kernel densities, but what is the green line? Is the green line a particular smoothing function?

[image: image in question]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The green line (straight) is the robust-regression line for each pair.
- The thick red line (curvy) is a non-parametric regression smoother (default is a gam, but you could change it)
- The dotted red lines represent some confidence envelope for the smoother (more specific description in the `spread` section of the help file)

Your question made me wonder if the color scheme is the same for me though, hence the curvy/straight qualifiers.